# Highchart remove Series 1 from chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a waterfall chart and I need to remove the Series 1 that appears on chart.
I already try:
legend: {
enabled: false
},
and
showInLegend: false,

But still apears.

```
chart: {
  type: 'waterfall'
},
title: {
  text: ''
},
exporting: {
  enabled: false
},
credits: {
  enabled: false
},
//colors: ['#DADBDF', '#ED4D5F','#ED4D5F','#ED4D5F','#ED4D5F','#ED4D5F','#D7EAFD','#D7EAFD','#D7EAFD' ],
xAxis: {
  lineColor: '#FFFFFF',
  lineWidth: 0,
  gridLineColor: '#DADBDF',
  categories: [],
},
yAxis: {
  lineColor: '#FFFFFF',
  lineWidth: 0,
  gridLineColor: '#DADBDF',
  plotBands: [{
    color: '#000000', // Color value
    from: 0, // Start of the plot band
    to: 0 // End of the plot band
  }],
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  tickPositioner: function () { //set tick interval dynamically (scale)
    var positions = [],
      tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
      increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 6);

    if (this.dataMax !== null && this.dataMin !== null) {
      for (tick; tick - increment <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
        positions.push(tick);
      }
    }
    return positions;
  }
},
legend: {
  enabled: false
},
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      color: '#000000'
    },
    colorByPoint: true,
    pointWidth: 150
  },
  series: {
    borderWidth: 0,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      format: '{point.y}'
    },
    turboThreshold: 0
  }
},
series: [{
  data: [],
  showInLegend: false,
  zones: [{
    value: 0,
    color: '#ED4D5F'
    }, {
      color: '#A9A9A9'
    }, {
      color: '#C48634'
    }, {
      color: '#696969'
    },{
    color: '#D7EAFD'
  }],
}],
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, that you have a series-label module enabled. Disable it in your chart config by setting *series.label.enabled* to **false**, or remove this module import from your HTML file.

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    label: {
      enabled: false
  }
}
```

}

---

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.label